# Varnish on Ubuntu 16 cannot read -f file custom default.vcl

Tags: ubuntu, varnish, systemd

I just installed a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 and I can't get Varnish to work with a custom config file, like I could with Ubuntu 14.04.

[I have read](http://deshack.net/how-to-varnish-listen-port-80-systemd/) that changes to `/etc/default/varnish` have no effect because it uses systemd instead of init.d.

So the process has changed to editing `/lib/systemd/system/varnish.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Varnish HTTP accelerator
Documentation=https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/4.1/ man:varnishd

[Service]
Type=simple
LimitNOFILE=131072
LimitMEMLOCK=82000
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/varnishd -j unix,user=vcache -F -a :6081 -T localhost:6082 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -S /etc/varnish/secret -s malloc,256m
ExecReload=/usr/share/varnish/reload-vcl
ProtectSystem=full
ProtectHome=true
PrivateTmp=true
PrivateDevices=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Now I want to swap the default.vcl with a custom vcl (which in a git repository that I'm working on).  So I change the line in ExecStart to have `-f /home/bozdoz/path/to/default.vcl`, and I get the following error after reloading the daemon and restarting the service:

```
>> sudo systemctl status varnish.service
● varnish.service - Varnish HTTP accelerator
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/varnish.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2016-09-07 14:29:58 ADT; 5s ago
     Docs: https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/4.1/
           man:varnishd
  Process: 7588 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/varnishd -j unix,user=vcache -F -a :6081 -T localhost:6082 -f /home/bozdoz/path/to/default.vcl
 Main PID: 7588 (code=exited, status=2)

Sep 07 14:29:58 bozdoz-dell systemd[1]: Started Varnish HTTP accelerator.
Sep 07 14:29:58 bozdoz-dell varnishd[7588]: Error: Cannot read -f file (/home/bozdoz/path/to/default.vcl)
```

I have tried changing the permissions on the custom file to be owned by varnish, or vcache, but neither worked.  I have tried opening the permissions to 777 (testing purposes only), but it still failed.

Also note, varnish works perfectly fine if I copy the custom file over to `/etc/varnish/default.vcl`; the issue is that I want the file to be in the git repository, but the varnish service doesn't seem able to access the custom file.

How can I use a custom file in another directory with systemd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the permissions on `/home/bozdoz` or one of the intermediate directories between `/home/bozdoz` and `default.vcl` is what's giving you this permission denied error.

If I can make a more general suggestion, it's bad practice to modify the service files in `/lib/systemd/system`. If the Varnish package is ever updated, it could potentially overwrite your changes. Instead, you have two options:

1. Copy `/lib/systemd/system/varnish.service` to `/etc/systemd/system/varnish.service` and make your changes there instead
2. Create a directory and file `/etc/systemd/system/varnish.service.d/override.conf` and apply a *delta* there

The `override.conf` would look something like this:

```
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/varnishd -j unix,user=vcache -F -a :6081 -T localhost:6082 -f /home/bozdoz/path/to/default.vcl -S /etc/varnish/secret -s malloc,256m
```

The first statement clears out the existing ExecStart directive, and the second sets a new one.

Comment: Still can't seem to solve any problem related to permissions; I might just copy the default.vcl file in the repo over to the /etc/varnish directory anytime I need to make changes.  Makes the most sense so far, if I can't use a custom file.

Comment: Hello thanks for you contribution, I have a question: what do you mean with: "apply a delta there"

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the permission issue, I believe `varnishd` might be running in a chroot jail which prevents it from accessing directories outside of `/etc/varnish`. So either you can copy your configuration to that directory or you can use `mount` with the `--bind` argument:

```
mkdir /etc/varnish/my-mount-point
mount --bind /home/bozdoz/path/to/ /etc/varnish/my-mount-point
```

Then in the varnish configuration you point to the file in `/etc/varnish/my-mount-point` directory. Any changes in your original directory will be reflected in the mounted directory.